# How a Javascript Object access Ionic Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, javascript-objects

```
app.service('JavascriptReflection', function($q, JSONStoreAPIServ) {
var Login = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name="";
    self.find = function() {
        //Call Ionic Service Here
    var dataFromDatabase = JSONStoreAPIServ.findLogin(self.Name);
        console.log('You are finding login ' + dataFromDatabase);
    }
}

var Customer = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = "";

    self.find = function() {
        var dataFromDatabase = JSONStoreAPIServ.findCustomer(self.Name);
        console.log('You are finding Customer ' + dataFromDatabase);
    }
}

var Database = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.find = function(obj) {
        if (typeof obj.find == 'function') {
            obj.find();
        }
    }
}
});

//At Controller.js
var db = new JavascriptReflection.Database();
var cust = new JavascriptReflection.Customer();
cust.Name = "Terry";
db.find(cust);
```

What I want to achieve is my Javascript Object able to access Ionic Service. Or can a Ionic Service able to have the same behavior of an object (as shown at code above). And can a Ionic Service call another Ionic Service? (should possible by injecting the Service Name inside). Please correct me if I am wrong or Ionic have other method that able to achieve the same goal?

Comment: can you provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: app.service('JavascriptReflection', function($q, JSONStoreAPIServ) {
//same code as above
var Login = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name="";
    self.find = function() {
        var a = JSONStoreAPIServ.Find(self.Name);
        console.log('You are finding login ' + a);
    }
}
});

Comment: edit your post, not a comment

Comment: _Call Ionic Service Here_ what ionic service you want call? Can you provide sample what you want, with needed ionic service?

Comment: ionic provide many services as angular service, and you can inject any of them to your service